# U-Tube Manometer vs Application

Tags: pressure, density

I am running an active vacuum distillation process on ethylene glycol (EG) and I am getting what I would call weird results. The setup is as shown in the picture. The vessel is held above 145°C to ensure continuous vaporization of the EG. The plumbing cools the vapors and establishes a liquid column leading to the trap (orange). The blue arrow is 48" and I am pulling 20 torr at the pump.

[image: Plumbing diagram of vacuum process]

I see this simply as the following image in terms of a U-tube manometer.

[image]

So the issue is that I am seeing 40 torr at the vessel, not 121 torr. The vacuum level in the vessel does not change with vessel temperature increases. Nor does the temperature of the EG within the vessel, which is stuck at the boiling point of EG at 40 torr (which makes sense).

Why am I seeing 40 torr at the vessel and not 121?

Anything you folks can provide would be amazing.

Comment: Something doesn't "add up" in your description.  The vacuum level in the system should be a function of EG vapor pressure, which is a function of temperature.  Therefore, the vacuum level of the vessel should change with temperature unless there is some type of control system which adds or subtracts small amounts of a gas that holds the vacuum level constant.  Also, why do you want to lower the vacuum in the system?

Comment: The vacuum pump is actively running. The reason I want the vacuum lower is to remove the EG from the system at a faster rater while keeping the temperatures lower to not compromise other materials in the vessel. This is basically a solvent extraction operation.

Comment: The rate of EG removal is constrained by the rate of heat transfer into the EG vessel.  Also note that the heat of vaporization will slightly increase as the boiling temperature goes down, meaning that the flow rate of EG vapor will slightly fall with falling pressure at a constant heat input.  You no doubt are describing an industrial process at your job, so you don't want to tell the public any proprietary information.  If you have any chemical engineers on your job, you may want to consult one or two of them.

Comment: I've scrubbed this of any information beyond what might be observed in a text book about distillation.

I am well aware that speed for removal is a function of heat input, but I am also aware that heat input is a function of delta T. Lowering the vacuum level reduces the boiling point of EG. If the vessel remains the same temperature, the delta T increases, resulting in more rapid removal.

Unfortunately, this has nothing to do with the question. Given that column height of liquid, how is that pressure differential possible?

Comment: If the dimensions on the glycol leg are correct and the vacuum pump suction pressure is correct, you should be seeing 121 torr in the glycol vessel.  If there is an independent pressure instrument, look at it.  Otherwise, calibrate a new pressure instrument and change out the old instrument, as it's not possible for it to read 40 torr.

Comment: I've got two such setups. Both read the same. Additionally, the EG temp is consistent with the boiling point of EG at 40 torr, about 118°C.

It sounds like you are starting to see my conundrum.

Comment: Make sure that the density of the EG in the manometer is what you expect.  In addition, make sure that your height measurements on the liquid leg in the manometer are correct.

Comment: Double checked leg. Looks like it's closer to 49", maybe 50" depending on how you look at it. As far as the density, the only other thing that could be in there is water. That might change the density a bit, but only about 11% (1.0 g/cc vs 1.11 g/cc). Eventually the water would boil out of the column (under vac) and only leave EG behind. There is nothing on the system that forms an azeotrope with EG either, so that's out as well.

Comment: You need to go with the "40 torr" number, as 3 out of 4 measurements are telling you the same thing.  Also, grab a sample of the manometer fluid, send it to the lab, and verify the density.  Assuming the density could be where the error lies.